Pure Javascript UI Components. Does such a thing exist?
Recognizing that Stackoverflow may not be the most appropriate place to ask, I figure folks here may have insights.
I want to render web (HTML) components using pure Javascript, but I haven't been able to find anything close. The myriad "tailwind", "bootstrap" clones all seem to want to bake display logic into HTML:
<div class="some indecipherable and incomprehensively long list of css classes which do magic things">

The alternative seems to be something like React, which has you writing HTML tags as strings:
function MyButton() {
  return (
    <button>I'm a button</button>
  );
}

This is "fine", but every React framework I've seen both requires significant learning, and seems hyper-bloated.
I want neither. I want to do something like this:
const modal = new Modal();
modal.text = 'Foobar';
modal.buttons = Button.OKCANCEL;
const result = modal.show();

Now this may create (will) create some html elements in the current DOM so the browser can render them, and it may add indecipherable CSS classes to those elements, but I don't want to have to know or care what it's doing. I assume it's going to create reactive elements, that work across browser etc.
I can unit test this, without having to do anything crazy like pixel-test generated screenshots etc. I assume if the javascript is written properly, it will render properly, so I only need to test the js code.
It's a mystery to me how people unit test apps built with these HTML UI "libraries" which are really just a collection of css classes.
Now I could create my own javascript classes, which just document.createElements a set of Bootstrap/Tailwind/etc HTML elements with the correct css classes, but why doesn't this already exist?
Or does it, and I just didn't RTFM?
Am I crazy?

User interfaces are hard.  They always have been.  You don't have to use all of that "indecipherable" CSS, but if you don't your web page will look like garbage.  THAT'S the problem.  Most people want their web pages to look good, and that takes hard work.

@TimRoberts I know it's hard, that's why I don't want to do it myself. I could take the collection of HTML and CSS classes that something like Bootstrap uses (to look good, and work correctly) and generate it using javascript (document.createElement etc), but I would rather leverage a framework that already exists. I am just confused by why there doesn't seem to already be such a thing (that I can find).

Your questions is mixed with various things. And I do not fully understand to which degree certain parts are relevant for the unit test thing and your question. Things like tailwind and the CSS parts of bootstrap or foundation are about standardized ways of styling, which can be used in anywhere. React, Svelt, and Vue are frameworks to use if you need reactivity (that the components automatically update if the state changes), to which you can apply styling using tailwind, bootstrap, foundation, … . If you don't need reactivity, then you are  maybe looking for HTMX.

If you don't need reactivity, and HTMX is not enough, then you maybe are just looking for Web Components.

@t.niese Basically I'm looking for something that produces results as appealing as Bootstrap/Tailwind etc, but which don't rely on hand-crafted HTML+CSS classes. E.g. the Modal in Bootstrap is a collection of DIVs with CSS classes. The results are great, but it seems brittle to me because one character wrong in a "class" string and something will break. Web Components seem fine, but the catalog of components is still pretty sparse, and the styling etc is left up to the reader.  My ideal is a pure JS api that produces Bootstrap (or whatever) HTML+CSS, along with the bindings for events etc.

That's why you have Frameworks such as Bootstrap and Tailwind in the first place. Frameworks also have downsides such as a high overhead and you can't solve everything with it. Most senior developer have written their own framework or at least a collection of commonly used CSS that they re-use.

but every [...] framework I've seen both requires significant learning and seems hyper-bloated. that's essentially the case for any UI library, no matter if it is for web or desktop environments. You basically always have the tradeoff between libraries/frameworks that support many features, which result in significant learning, or barebone libraries where you have to do everything yourself. It's a mystery to me how people unit test apps built with these HTML UI "libraries"  unit testing UIs is always a pain.

Now I could create my own javascript classes, which just document.createElements a set of Bootstrap/Tailwind/etc HTML elements with the correct css classes, but why doesn't this already exist? for all of the mayor frameworks like React, Vue, Svelte there are UI component libraries, for which use just use the components and set the properties and those apply the classes.

because the job of HTML is just to format documents. for JS to allow basic scripting. It is not intended to be a huge bloated library which only reduces browser performance, requires more space and would cause longer loading times. Thos languages are specified for performance and giving the devs necessary tools so they can created the stuff they need themself.
